# How to get the rotation Angle of Euler Angle ZYX rotation order in unity？

Tags: unity-game-engine

Now I have a 4 * 4 matrix and I want to get the angles along the ZYX rotation direction by the matrix.
Are there any specific conversion functions?

unity has a quaternion conversion function for Euler angles, but the order of the conversion is zxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `rotation` of the `Matrix4x4` which will give you a `Quaternion`. From there you can get the Euler angles with `eulerAngles`.

So:

```
Quaternion rotation = matrix.rotation;
Vector3 eulerAngles = rotation.eulerAngles;
```